# Potential energies of charges and spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, spring

I wonder if someone could sanity check this very simple calculation.

Consider a pair of charges $+q$ at rest separated by a spring of length $d$ and stiffness $k$.

The spring provides the force that balances the electrostatic repulsion of the charges. If the spring is stretched by an amount $x$ we have:

$$k\ x = \frac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0d^2}$$

The electrostatic energy of the pair of charges is given by:

$$E_{em}=\frac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0d}$$

so that we have:

$$k\ x=\frac{E_{em}}{d}$$

The potential energy stored in the spring is given by:

$$E_S=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$$

$$E_S=\frac{1}{2} E_{em}\frac{x}{d}$$

Let us suppose that the spring is stiff ($k$ is large) so that:

$$\frac{x}{d}<<1$$

Is it true that the energy stored in the spring $E_S$ is much less than the electrostatic energy $E_{em}$?

Answer (score 2):

Variations of this problem show up all the time. If you start with the spring "locked" and the spheres charged, then release the spring, it will expand to the new length *and when it gets there the spheres will have a velocity* - essentially you have a simple harmonic oscillator and the point of (new) equilibrium is the point where the oscillator moved fastest. Kinetic energy in the middle equals potential energy at the end, and the rest follows.

Your math is correct but misses the velocity term. If you did the experiment differently - namely you added charge very slowly and let the spring expand as the spheres charged - the factor 2 would disappear. Similarly if you added friction as the spring extended, the work done against the friction would consume the other half of the potential energy,